# Visual Studio Code "python.h: No such file or directory" windows gcc

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, compilation

I 'm a total beginner in **C++** and getting crazy trying to embed **Python** in **C++** using **VS Code** IDE and **GCC** compiler.
I am stock and now I 'm keep facing this silly error that says:

> python.h: No such file or directory gcc

I have followed steps explaned in ["Using GCC with MinGW in VS Code"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) in order to configure **C++** in **VS Code** but I failed to install **MinGW** (The bin folder was empty) so I add already installed **CodeBlocks MinGW** to my path and it seems to work.

I have **python 3.8** installed and tried other solutions and already put **Python.h** and **python library path** in project include path.

> "C:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/include/**"
> and
> "C:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/libs/**"

here is the code that I want to compile:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <python.h>

    int main()
{
    PyObject* pInt;

    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello World from Embedded Python!!!')");
    
    Py_Finalize();

    printf("\nPress any key to exit...\n");
    if(!_getch()) _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my **c_cpp_properties.json**. (C++ configuration file):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/include/**",
                "C:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/libs/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and this is **tasks.json** file:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: \"C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe\""
    }
]
```

}

Comment: How are you building the code? `c_cpp_properties.json` only configures the intellisense

Comment: You need to modify `tasks.json` to tell the compiler itself how to build, and what flags, options and arguments should be used for the compiler.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am following build steps from [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I provided **tasks.json** file codes

Comment: use a build tool if you need other includes than de standard ones, you usually have more than 1, makes your life a lot simpler, also because you mostly have more than 1 C++ file, you forget to specify where to find the `python.h`, use compile option `-I` (capital i), don't forget the `-L` option and specify the python lib, order of arguments is important

Comment: @rioV8 Is this should be done in **tasks.json** file that I mentioned? can you provide an example of using the arguments?

Comment: You need to add `-I`, `-L` and `-l` options into `tasks.json`.

Comment: this is my args now: `["-g","-o","-I","-L","-l","${file}",${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
   ]` and the new error `Starting build...
"C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" -g -o -I -L -l "E:\Univercity\Term 6\Information retrieval\Assignments\a3\persian_preprocessor\main.cpp" "E:\Univercity\Term 6\Information retrieval\Assignments\a3\persian_preprocessor\main.exe"
gcc.exe: error: E:\Univercity\Term 6\Information retrieval\Assignments\a3\persian_preprocessor\main.exe: No such file or directory`

Comment: I suggest you find some documentation or tutorial about the `-I`, `-L` and `-l` options. You don't use them correctly.

Comment: This can be off-topic but I would suggest using QtCreator for Windows that's free and brings MINGW64 integrated as a compiler option.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited args like this `"-I",
    "C:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/include",
    "-iquote","C:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/include",
    "C:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/libs","-g","${file}","-o",${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"` now it says `undefined reference to _imp__Py_Initialize`

Comment: Not to be discouraging, but "total beginner in C++" and "trying to embed Python" is not an ideal combination. Embedding Python is more at the "intermediate to advanced" level.

Comment: The `-I` option (upper-case i) it to add directories to search for header files. You've got that part right. The `-L` option does the same for libraries, it's add a directory to search for libraries. The `-l` (lower-case L) option must be placed after all source and object files, and tells which actual libraries to link with.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `"-IC:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/include",
    "-lPython.h",
    "-LC:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/libs",
    "-lpython38.lib"` error: cannot find -lPython.h

Comment: `Python.h` is a *header file* not a library. Include header files, link with libraries.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you please provide a simple example of it. I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was a combinations of simple mistakes and as a beginner I solved it by some digging in [gcc -l -L option flags for library link example](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html) and [gcc arguments docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html).

There are several simple and important points that should be observed:

**1.** The order of options is really important. If its wrong, compiler wont work. It should be like -I(capital i),-g,-L,-l(lower case L),-o.

**2.** To embed python in C++ firstly the path to python **include files** have to be known to compiler by **-I** option. Then the path to **python libraries** by a **-L** option. Then name of the each required python **.lib file** contained in libs folder of python.

Here is an example of it:

```
            "-IC:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/include",=>(path to python include files) 
            "-g",=>(debug option specified by ide)
            "${file}",
            "-LC:/Users/MPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/libs",=>(path to python libraries)
            "-lpython38",=>(python lib contained in python libs)
            "-lpython3",=>(python lib contained in python libs)
            "-l_tkinter",=>(python lib contained in python libs)
            "-o",=>(output argument specified by ide)
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
```

I hope that with this answer, the beginners like me, get to the conclusion faster.
There is also a good youtube tutorial of  [Embedding python in C++ with CMake and Pybind11 and VS Code](https://youtu.be/-eIkUnCLMFc)

Comment: For future readers if your code is compiling fine, however you are still getting underline errors on vscode for windows using g++/mingw or similar you may also need to update the c_cpp_properties.json file by adding the Include path to Intellisense. do the below

"name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/python3.10"

Answer (score -2):

Ok so you should probably go through like a intermediate c++ course first, but if u are a begginer and you really want to do this I recommend using visual studio 2019 or 2022, because it is way more begginer-friendly and the dependencies are all set in a gui interface.
BTW i would've commented this but I don't have 50 reputation yet so sorry.